# Multithreaded simple deadlock bug evading detection

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I am learning `multithreading` in class, so please no implemented solutions; improvement suggestions are appreciated though.

A 10,000 ft overview: main accepts 3 parameters (threads, resources, and runtime length). Each thread waits a random time, then decides to access the shared resources/critical section for a random time, upon completion relinquishing the resource. Repeat for provided runtime length, then exit all threads.

Based on the problem of users at a gocart track, taking turns riding and wandering around between rides.

I've created a deadlock, but I cannot find how that could be.

Sleeper just assigns the thread to wait for a time.

Rider class:

```
public void run() {
        while (!coord.exit) {
            System.out.format("Rider %d is gone walkabout%n", ID);
            Sleeper.walkAround(ID);
            System.out.format("Rider %d is in line%n", ID);
            try {
            carID = coord.getInLine();
            System.out.format("Rider %d is riding car %d%n", ID, carID);
            Sleeper.rideTime(ID);
            coord.returnCar(carID);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {System.out.println("Thread " + ID + " was interrupted.");}
        }
    }
```

The Coordinator class is where the meat is:

```
public class Coordinator {

    Rider[] riderArr;
    Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
    Semaphore cars;
    LinkedList<Integer> carLine;
    volatile static boolean exit = false;

    public synchronized int getInLine() throws InterruptedException {
        cars.acquire();
        mutex.acquire();
        int carid = carLine.removeFirst();
        mutex.release();
        return carid;
    }

    public synchronized void returnCar(int carID) throws InterruptedException {
        mutex.acquire();
        carLine.add(carID);
        mutex.release();
        cars.release();
    }

    public Coordinator(int cars, int riders) {
        riderArr = new Rider[riders];
        for (int i = 0; i < riders; i++) {
            riderArr[i] = new Rider(this, i + 1);
        }
        carLine = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cars; i++) {
            carLine.add(i + 1);
        }
        this.cars = new Semaphore(cars);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, InterruptedException {
        Coordinator coord = new Coordinator(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),
                Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(args[1]); i++) {
            coord.riderArr[i].start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000 * Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
        exit = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(args[1]); i++) {
            coord.riderArr[i].join();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Here is the console output for a deadlocked session:

```
Rider 2 is gone walkabout
Rider 2 is walking around for  4 seconds
Rider 1 is gone walkabout
Rider 1 is walking around for  1 seconds
Rider 1 is in line
Rider 1 is riding car 1
Rider 1 is riding for 3 seconds
Rider 2 is in line
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @natecat how can a spin lock arise given the two synchronized methods?

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused how a `Semaphore` equals a spin lock.  There seems to be no question here, suggest the Code Review site would be better.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you mean a deadlock?

Comment: @natecat spin lock is just the term we were taught in class. It looks like the two terms are referring to the same situation

Comment: @DougClark No they aren't, spinlock is a specific type of lock, deadlock is when 2+ threads block each other indefinitely

Comment: @Natecat So spinlock and busy-wait are synonymous? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DougClark In a sense, busy wait is more general, and doesn't specifically have to do with threading. Spinlock is an implementation of busy waiting though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a deadlock scenario:

- N Threads acquire all N `Semaphore` tokens in `cars`
- Thread X enters `getInLine` and waits for `cars#acquire`

Because `getInLine` is `synchronized` and X has the lock, there is no way for any of the N threads to return a token. This is because `returnCar` method is also  `synchronized`

---

A better way to achieve your goal would be to place `carLine#removeFirst` and `carLine#add` in `synchronized` methods of their own, and remove `synchronized` from the other two methods:

```
public synchronized int removeCar(){
    return carLine.removeFirst();
}

public synchronized void addCar(int car){
    carLine.add(car);
}
```

This also removes your need of a `mutex` object. You instead use the `Coordinator` object itself as the mutex. It also means that waiting for an `acquire` on the Semaphore wont block you from returning its tokens

Comment: So I didn't want to override LinkedLists methods, I just removed 'synchronized' and kept the mutex. I misunderstood what 'synchronized' did, I'm still fuzzy but I'll look into it more. Thanks!

Comment: @DougClark in Java you can use any Object you want as a mutex, or more specifically a reentrant lock. There are two ways to use synchronized; on a method (using the entire class instance as the lock) or in a block `sychronized(obj){ }` (using the object in the `( )` as the lock). The thread that calls synchronized will have the lock on the object until the method exits or leaves the block. If another thread reaches `synchronized` while the first thread has the lock, it will wait until the first thread returns the lock.